# Trigger 2 forms from the click of 1 button

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I need to allow the click of 1 button to allow the view to trigger the controller to save the values it is holding in session and thereafter trigger the form which directs to a payment gateway.

When I am running it locally it works all fine but as soon as I publish it, whenever I click the button it does nothing.

Could someone maybe help me out and point out whats wrong?

Many Thanks

```
<input type="submit" value="Make Payment" onclick="myFunction()"/>   

 <script>
    function myFunction()
    {
        $('#cont').submit(doubleSubmit);

        function doubleSubmit(e1) {
            e1.preventDefault();
            e1.stopPropagation();

            var post_form1 = $.post($(this).action, $(this).serialize());

            post_form1.done(function (result) {
                // would be nice to show some feedback about the first result here

                $('#paym').submit();
            });
        };
    }
</script>

 @using (Html.BeginForm("reservation_step_3", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "cont" }))
   {

        //code which allows controller to write to DB

   }

    <form name="Post" action="https://virtual.mygateglobal.com/PaymentPage.cfm" method="post" id="paym">
  //code for redirect to payment gateway
    </form>
```